# ComboBox for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, combobox

I'm trying to make a combobox in ASP.NET MVC 3.0 where the user can either type in a value in a text field or select a value from a drop down.  The user should not be restricted to the values in the select list.  The view has a viewmodel, so the values need to be populated and posted to the controller action through model binding.

I've [created a decent jquery solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10341126/529612) based on the jquery autocomplete widget, but I haven't got it to play well with the MVC unobtrusive javascript validation.  I'm making progress with [this HtmlHelper extension](http://www.veadas.net/article/aspnet-mvc-combo-box), but I'm wrestling with UI issues with IE/compatibility mode and my existing CSS.  Paying for a control suite like Telerik or Infragistics is not possible. (EDIT: This is a commercial app, so I can't use the free Telerik controls because they are GPL and if you use a GPL component in your app, your entire app becomes GPL).

Does anyone have a great ComboBox for MVC?

Answer (score 2):

See [Adding a New Category to the DropDownList using jQuery UI](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/adding-a-new-category-to-the-dropdownlist-using-jquery-ui) 
Originally I hacked a jQuery plugin to allow the user to enter a new FK field (in this case Genre or Artist). There is no HTML UI that allows a combobox entry, so I went in another direction. My tutorial also uses the chosen jquery plugin, altho it doesn't allow input.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the features of the **chosen jquery plugin** to meet the needs of a javascript-enhanced dropdownlist nicely.

The component is from the Harvest development team.  There's a bit of documentation and the download [here](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/).

I especially like that it's under MIT license so no ownership or modification rights issues to worry about.